# Where do unanswered questions go?

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

I was doing research on some issues and found out that there are some question without answers. I also [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846658/make-wordpress-submenu-page-with-settings-field-using-object-oriented-programmin) but got no answers. Is there a way for these to be curated? What happens to unanswered questions?

Comment: [tracker comment]

Comment: After thirty days if negatively scored, or a year if zero scored, they are deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba. What do you mean by *"curated"*? You can *search* for unanswered questions if you want to, and either answer them or place a bounty to encourage others to do so.